# Problem with reading image from esp32 using python

Tags: python, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to stream video from esp32 to python **not using wi-fi streaming**.

My first plan is esp32 send encode image for base64 and python reads it line by line then decode it to image. Then use opencv to stream video.
Arduino serial monitor can read image encoded base64 but python reads nothing. It only **reads just b''**.

I double checked port and baud rate but I don't no what is problem
please help me...

ESP32

```c
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*

  ESP32CAM | Android(Flutter App) Wired Communication - Base64 Encoding/Decoding [2/2]

  Video Tutorial: https://youtu.be/-jygTxRmroA
  https://github.com/0015/ThatProject/commit/40b4c19495591b60a659f8946b6a4811556ade36
  Created by Eric N. (ThatProject)

*/

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <base64.h>
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER


#define BAUD_RATE 2000000
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
    cameraInit();
}

void loop() {
    grabImage();
}

void cameraInit() {
    camera_config_t config;
    config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
    config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
    config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
    config.xclk_freq_hz = 10000000;
    config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_QVGA; //320x240
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;

    esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
      return;
    }

    sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
    s->set_hmirror(s, 1);   
    s->set_vflip(s, 1);   
}

void grabImage() {
    camera_fb_t* fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb || fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
    } else {
        delay(40);
        String enter = "\n";
        String encoded = base64::encode(fb->buf, fb->len);
        encoded = encoded + enter;
        Serial.write(encoded.c_str(), encoded.length());
        // Serial.println();
    }
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}
```

Python

```py
cam = serial.Serial(
    port='COM7',
    baudrate=2000000,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0
)

cam.close()

cam.setDTR(False)
cam.setRTS(False)
cam.open()

for _ in range(5):
    # cam.close()
    # cam.open()
    print(cam.readline())
```

Comment: import serial, base64  >> I forgot to write this in question, my python code has this

Comment: Eliminate complexity to debug. If you ignore the camera code and run an Arduino program that outputs a few lines of text what does the Python script do?

Comment: Python reads line and if it reads well then decode the string to image.  That code is just to test python reads data well. Am I understand what you said? cus i'm not good at english

Comment: Sorry, kraburn. it dosn't work either. python reads only b''. Serial monitor for esp32 with arduino 1.8.19 presnts decoded image